# Why $F=\{p(a) \mid p∈k[x]\}$ is a field?

Tags: field-theory

If $k$ is a subfield of $K$ and $a\in K$. Why the set $F=\{p(a) \mid p∈k[x]\}$ is a field?

I think that this is a trivial question but I can't do it by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism
$$\varphi:k[x] \to K,\phantom{aa}p(x)\mapsto p(a)$$
Obviously, $\text{im}\varphi=F$. Moreover 
$$\ker\varphi=\{p(x) \in k[x]:p(a)=0\}$$
We now see the following: Your claim is false if $a$ is transcendent over $k$, because in this case, $\ker\varphi=\{0\}$. It follows that $\varphi$ is injective. Hence $k[x]\cong F$. But $k[x]$ is not a field.

However, if $a$ is algebraic over $k$, your claim is true. The reason is that $\ker\varphi$ is an ideal in $k[x]$ which is generated by the minimum polynomial of $a$ over $k$. Since this polynomial is irreducible in $k[x]$, it follows that $k[x]/\ker\varphi$ is a field. Using the homomorphism theorem for rings, we have
$$k[x]/\ker\varphi\cong F$$
Therefore, $F$ is a field.